# How to create a struct with different structs of one members of struct in go?

Tags: json, go, struct

I am getting a json response from a server with three fix json object field and one field with different json objects.

Example - Response 1

```
{
   status : "success",
   error-code : "",
   message : "login successful",
   data : {
           token : "token value",
           refresh-token : "refresh token value"
          }
}
```

Example - Response 2

```
{
   status : "success",
   error-code : "",
   message : "user data fetched",
   data : {
           first-name: "josh",
           last-name : "walter",
           age : "30",
           phone: 1234567890,
           address : "x street, dc"
          }
}
```

for above json response created struct as follows

```
type loginData struct {
    Token string `json:"token"`
    RefreshToken string `json:"refresh-token"`

}

type userdata {
    FirstName string    `json:"first-name"`
    LastName string     `json:"refresh-token"`
    Age string          `json:"age"`
    Phone string        `json:"phone"`
    Address string      `json:"address"`

}


type response struct {
    Status string       `json:"status"`
    ErrorCode string    `json:"error-code"`
    RespMessage string  `json:"message"`
    RespData string     `json:"data"`
}
```

How to add logindata struct while unmarshaling during login response and userdata struct while unmarshaling userdata response in "RespData" field in response struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mkopriva as you said tried this suggestion it worked.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type loginData struct {
    Token        string `json:"token"`
    RefreshToken string `json:"refresh-token"`
}

type userdata struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first-name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last-name"`
    Age       string `json:"age"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
}

type response struct {
    Status      string      `json:"status"`
    ErrorCode   string      `json:"error-code"`
    RespMessage string      `json:"message"`
    RespData    interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    jsonresp_1 := `{
        "status" : "success",
        "error-code" : "",
        "message" : "login successful",
        "data" : {
                "token" : "token value",
                "refresh-token" : "refresh token value"
               }
     }`

    jsonresp_2 := `{
        "status" : "success",
        "error-code" : "",
        "message" : "user data fetched",
        "data" : {
                "first-name": "josh",
                "last-name" : "walter",
                "age" : "30",
                "phone": "1234567890",
                "address" : "x street, dc"
               }
     }`
    resp1 := strings.NewReader(jsonresp_1)
    data1 := loginData{}
    respdata1 := response{RespData: &data1}

    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp1).Decode(&respdata1); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("token : %s \nrefreshtoken : %s \n", data1.Token, data1.RefreshToken)

    fmt.Println("-------------------")

    resp2 := strings.NewReader(jsonresp_2)
    data2 := userdata{}
    respdata2 := response{RespData: &data2}

    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp2).Decode(&respdata2); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("firstname : %s \nlastname : %s ", data2.FirstName, data2.LastName)
}
```

## Output

```
⚡ ⇒  go run main.go 
token : token value 
refreshtoken : refresh token value 
-------------------
firstname : josh 
lastname : walter
```

Answer (score 2):

First change the `RespData` field's type:

```golang
type response struct {
    Status      string      `json:"status"`
    ErrorCode   string      `json:"error-code"`
    RespMessage string      `json:"message"`
    RespData    interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

Then, depending on what request you are making, set the `RespData` field to a pre-allocated instance of a pointer to the expected type:

```golang
r, err := http.Get("https://some_api.com/loginData")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer r.Body.Close()

// check r.StatusCode and make sure it's correct

data := loginData{}
resp := response{RespData: &data}
if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&resp); err != nil {
    return err
}

fmt.Println(data)
```

Comment: please check code below added answer

Comment: @supapati what for should I check the code in "below added answer"?

Comment: whether it is correct as you said to do..

Comment: @supapati if it works then it's correct, wouldn't you say so?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should have two different `structs` to do this. One reason is separation of concern, as the structure of these responses may change in the future and these are responses from two different apis so its better to maintain different response objects.

```golang
type loginData struct {
    Token        string `json:"token"`
    RefreshToken string `json:"refresh-token"`
}

type userdata struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first-name"`
    LastName  string `json:"refresh-token"`
    Age       string `json:"age"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
}

type response struct {
    Status      string `json:"status"`
    ErrorCode   string `json:"error-code"`
    RespMessage string `json:"message"`
}

type userResponse struct {
    response
    RespData userdata `json:"data"`
}

type loginResponse struct {
    response
    RespData loginData `json:"data"`
}
```

Comment: I think this will workout will check n revert ..

Comment: I tried your suggestion but  we get 27 different API responses in data field for each response, so  have  to create two struct each one child one parent. so there will be reusable code.

Comment: This will tedious if you have too many apis, I guess @mkopriva is an easier approach.